# django how to override an error page to a specific endpoint?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to override the `500 error` view https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/views/

I have implemented `500.html` but I want to ensure that any instance of a `500` gets redirected to my own custom specific endpoint (say `my-error/`)

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: does [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) achieve what you need?

Comment: Why do you want to redirect on error?

Comment: Note that you should not redirect on error, this means the browser receives a 302, not a 500 back. That's really bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

By using django's custom [customized error-views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views), you can specify custom views for handling 500 errors such as:

```py
# urls.py
handler500 = 'my_app.views.custom_error_view'
```

```py
# views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def custom_error_view(request):
    msg = "500 error!"
    return HttpResponse(msg, status_code=500)
```